# Combining VR and 360 panorama with Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, virtual-reality

Is it possible to combine a 360 panorama (made with three-css3d) with VR made with Three.js, StereoEffect.js and other Three.js plugins.

[Example for 360 panorama](http://threejs.org/examples/#css3d_panorama)

[VR example/tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/bringing-vr-to-web-google-cardboard-three-js/)

Eventually I'd like to make a 360 panorama in VR...